# how to create @webservlet url pattern like REST

Tags: servlets, servlet-3.0

Im tryign to create a url like the following, is this even allowed, using annotation @WebServlet ?

urlPatterns = { "/name/*/title" }

I can the following to work

urlPatterns = { "/name/*" }

I am completely new to this, i want to do something like rest type thing, i know how to do this using spring mvc. but here im limited to webservlets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes the urlPattern `urlPatterns = { "/name/*/title" }` is completely legal and should work fine.

You can declare it like

```
@WebServlet( 
  urlPatterns={"/one/*/abc"} , 
  name="ServletOne", 
  initParams={ 
     @WebInitParam(name = "name", value = "abc") 
  }
)
```

***How-ever, keep in mind that here `*` is not treated as a wild-card***. Servlets do not support wild-cards patterns in the middle of the mapping. So `/name/*/title` does not mean `/name/<anything>/title`.

**Edit**

If you want to hit a URL like `/name/*/title` where `*` can be anything, then the URL `/one/*` should serve the purpose just fine.

Comment: thank you @Saif Asif, but i wanted the (*) to be anything, for example: /name/<something>/title. Which as you said doesnt work. What about having  <anything>/name/title, would that work? i dont think it would it?

Comment: No `<anything>/name/title` is also invalid. Although these are legal
`/name/*` and 
`/*`